# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException while Downloading Files from FTP Server

Tags: groovy, ftp

> I want to create job in grails which download the files from ftp
>   server after certain interval of time say 2-3 days and store it on
>   specified local path. the same code with minor changes is written in
>   java which was working fine but when write the similar code in Grails
>   I'm facing the Error and not able to resolve it. Can any body Tell me
>   where I'm making mistake?

**Following is the Error that I'm facing when job start.**

```
JOB STARTED::************************************************************************************
2015-08-24 18:20:35,285 INFO    org.quartz.core.JobRunShell:207 Job GRAILS_JOBS.com.hoteligence.connector.job.DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ftpClient for class: com.hoteligence.connector.job.DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob [See nested exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ftpClient for class: com.hoteligence.connector.job.DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ftpClient for class: com.hoteligence.connector.job.DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob
    at com.hoteligence.connector.job.DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob.execute(DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob.groovy:93)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 more
```

---

```
            /* I've added all the related dependencies in grails Build Config.
            */

package com.hoteligence.connector.job

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as ConfigHolder;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
/**
 * @author Gajanan
 * this is back-end job which download Files from ftp server and store it on locally
 */
class DownloadIpgGzipFilesJob {


    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: Long.parseLong(ConfigHolder.config.DEVICE_PING_ALERT_JOB_REPEAT_INTERVAL),
        startDelay : 60000
    }

    def execute() {

        try{

            println "JOB STARTED::************************************************************************************";
            /* following is the details which are required for server connectivity  
            */
            String server = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_SERVER_NAME;
            int port = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_SERVER_PORT_NO;
            String user = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_SERVER_USER_NAME;
            String pass = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_SERVER_USER_PASSWORD;
            String [] fileNames = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_DOWNLOADABLE_GZIP_FILE_LIST.split(",");
            String downloadFilePath = ConfigHolder.config.IPG_GZIP_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION;
            String fileDate = (todaysDate.getYear()+1900)+""+((todaysDate.getMonth()+1)<=9?("0"+(todaysDate.getMonth()+1)):(todaysDate.getMonth()+1))+""+todaysDate.getDate();

            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();


            /* Here we are making connection to the server and the reply
             from server is printed on console
            */

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);

            int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Connect failed");
                return;
            }

            boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);

            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                return;
            }



            /* Here we are iterate the FileList and download them to specified directory

            */
            for(int i =0; i<fileNames.length;i++) {
                String fileName = "on_"+ConfigHolder.config.IPG_DATA_COUNTRY_CODE+fileNames[i]+fileDate+".xml.gz";

                System.out.println(fileName);
                downloadFtpFileByName(ftpClient,fileName,downloadFilePath+fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            // logs out and disconnects from server

            /* In finally block we forcefully close the connection and close the file node also

            */
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

            /* this function is nothing but to print the ftp server reply after connection to ftp server

            */
    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }


            /* This is the actual logic where we copy the file from ftp 
             and store on local directory
             this method accept three parameter FtpClient object, Name of the file which has to be downloaded from server and the path where downloaded file has to be stored
            */

    private static void downloadFtpFileByName(FTPClient ftpClient,String fileName,String downloadfileName){

        System.out.println("Strat Time::"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {

            String remoteFile1 = "/"+fileName; // file on server 
            File downloadFile1 = new File(downloadfileName); // new file which is going to be copied on local directory
            OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1)); 
            Boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);


            if (success) {
                System.out.println("File"+fileName+" has been downloaded successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File"+fileName+" has been DOWNLOAD FAILURE....");
            }

            outputStream1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("END Time::"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line:

```
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
```

Outside of the `try { ... } catch()` block (ie, move it up to before the `try`)

You are declaring the local variable inside the try, then trying to use it in the `finally` block

Comment: Yea you are right. now it's not giving the error but not stopping when debug point is set inside code.?